# In Rails 3 how does the simple_form_for method know whether to include the params[:id] in the action attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, dry

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to figure out how to make the [action] attribute on a form dynamic so that I can reuse the form markup.

In MVC.net it's easy as you usually specify the :controller and :action.

However in rails there's just a "**simple_form_for(@my_model)**" method.

If I browse to **/my_models/new** the action attribute is:

```
action = "/my_models"
```

But if I go to **/my_models/1/edit** the action attribute is:

```
action = "my_models/1"
```

What if I want to create a new action for handling POSTs of my_model AND still reuse the same _form.html.erb... how does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's actually rails doing this
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L230

In short it just infers the url based on the resource and whether it is new or an existing one.

SimpleForm's FormBuilder is inherited from ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

You can check out that code https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb

I guess I'm not understanding the last part. Say you wanted to use a custom action instead of the inferred ones you could just make a partial of the form elements and use that partial for all forms.

so _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form_elements' %>
<% end %>
```

_custom_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @my_object, :url => custom_url do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form_elements' %>
<% end %>
```

_form_elements.html.erb

```
form elements as usual
```